# Creating Complete Alpha-Ranges from the end string

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a dataframe like so:

```
Mode    End
1      ANDE
2      BABI
2      BEAT
3      ZZZZ
```

I'm trying to create complete alpha ranges, I'd like to end up with:

```
Mode  Start     End
1      AAAA    ANDE
2      ANDF    BABI
2      BABJ    BEAT
3      BEAU    ZZZZ
```

How in python do i accomplish something like this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  How would you do this by hand?  What code have you developed so far?

Comment: The adjacent cases are trivial: use the `ord` and `chr` functions to get the previous letter.  For instance, `chr(ord('E') + 1)` will return `F`.  You'll need to handle the roll-over cases, such as the successor of `BUZZ` being `BTAA`.  Can you advance from there?

Comment: The only thing i can think to do is a bunch of slicing/if statements, which seems silly so i didn't post it.. I'm unsure if there a way to operate on characters in this manner, i tried googling and can't find anything that's not regex, which doesn't help. How is this not a valid question?

Comment: I can, thanks Prune.

Comment: @Prune successor is `BVAA` - no?

Comment: @AChampion: Yes, it's `BVAA`.  Thanks.

Comment: @JustinLeonard: in general, Stack Overflow doesn't handle questions of the type "Please write this block of code for me."  Show your work, describe the problem, and *then* I expect you'll get better responses.  That's why I made sure you had a starting point.  Think of how you'd handle this with a string of length 1000.  Consider using a "next letter" sequence of your own, such as "ABC...XYZA", so all you have to do is grab the next letter in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a successor function to each value in `End` and `roll` it (successor of `ZZZZ` is `AAAA` in the appropriate base), e.g. (assumes all uppercase values):

```
In []:
def successor(s):
    d, r = 1, []
    for c in reversed(s):
        d, m = divmod(ord(c) - ord('A') + d, 26)
        r.append(chr(m + ord('A')))
    return ''.join(reversed(r))

df['Start'] = np.roll(df['End'].apply(successor), 1)
df
Out[]:
       End Start
Mode            
1     ANDE  AAAA
2     BABI  ANDF
2     BEAT  BABJ
3     ZZZZ  BEAU
```

If you care about column order, just use `df.insert(...)`.
If you can't guarantee the end is `'ZZZZ'`, then you can just `shift()` the result of the `apply()` and replace the `NaN` with `'AAAA'`.

```
In []:
df.insert(0, 'Start', df['End'].apply(successor).shift().fillna('AAAA'))
df
Out[]:
     Start   End
Mode            
1     AAAA  ANDE
2     ANDF  BABI
2     BABJ  BEAT
3     BEAU  ZZZZ
```

Comment: Much much simpler than the road i was heading down. thank you!